# will the commands in Dockerfile run as follows?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
docker build Dockerfile .//running it correctly.
```

1.) I have mentioned in the comments each command will execute as written, Is that correct working of this Dockerfile?

2.)These commands will be used to make the image when I ran docker build, so

[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$cd /project/p1

[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx p1]$ls

Dockerfile a b c d

My Dockerfile consists of following commands.

**Dockerfile**

```
node 8.1.0 //puls the image from hub

RUN mkdir -p /etc/x/y   //make directory in the host at path /etc/x/y

RUN mkdir /app     //make directory in the host at path /app

COPY . /app     //copy all the files that is 
WORKDIR /app    //cd /app; now the working directory will be /app for next commands i.e npm install.

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000  //what this will do?
```

Comment: Yes it runs from top to bottom.
Expose opens the ports for other containers on the same network but NOT the host.

Comment: but I dont find /app directory on my host, and the image is also built for this.

Comment: Well, the `app` directory is created in the container copying all the data from the folder you build the image from. That is because you use the `COPY . /app` which pretty much means "copy everything in current folder to the containers /app directory".

Comment: Also, in the comments you are either mixing up host and container or you have misunderstood: The commands you run in the image will not affect the host computer, but only the image and the containers that you use the image for.

Comment: my unserstanding is that, host is what my computer here or ec2, and container is a process that runs the image inside it.Now, when I write mkdir -p /etc/x/y I saw this path in the host, so when I make mkdir /app I did not see the path. that is the problem I am facing.

Comment: Right. The `host` is the computer, but in the comments you write `make directory in the host at path /app` which is not what happens. If you do `RUN mkdir /app` in the image, it will create a directory for the containers, not the host.

Comment: okay, it means when we write mkdir /something it will make a directory in the container, okay but why i am able to see the path /etc/x/y in my local?

Comment: I would guess that you have that folder even before running the build command.

Comment: fine got it the whole concept, thank you so much.:)

Comment: No problem. Docker and everything around it can be rather confusing, but when you get it right its one of the best tools out there! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1: how to run docker build?

```
docker build Dockerfile . # am I running it correctly.
```

No, you run it with `docker build .` and docker will automatically look for the `Dockerfile` in the current directory. Or you use `docker build -f Path_to_the_docker_file/DockerFile` where you clearly specify the path to the `DockerFile`.

### Question 2: Fixing errors and clarifying commands

There are few mistakes in the **Dockerfile**, check the edited comments:

```
# pulls the image from dockerhub : YES 
# Needs to be preceeded with FROM  
FROM node 8.1.0 

# all directories are made inside the docker image
# make directory in the image at path /etc/x/y : YES
RUN mkdir -p /etc/x/y   
# make directory in the image at path /app : YES
RUN mkdir /app     

COPY . /app     # copy all the files that is : YES 
WORKDIR /app    # cd /app; now the working directory will be /app for next commands i.e npm install. : YES

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000  # what this will do? => tells all docker instances of this image to listen on port 3000.
```